# Search for multiple Order IDs using one form field and union query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a form that allows users to look up multiple order IDs in one textbox field separating the IDs with commas.

I have a union query that is looking at two databases to collect information on client orders to help us determine supplies we need to order on our purchase orders.

With the query, I can use the OR function to search multiple orders that are in production. So for example, If I wanted to search for supplies needed for order ID: 6101, 6102, 6103, 6104 I would put this information in the Criteria section of the orderID field:

```
=6101 Or 6102 Or 6103 Or 6104
```

What I am trying to create is a form where users can input the list of OrderIDs they want to search for in one text box field like so:

> 6101, 6102, 6103, 6104

What I am not sure how to do is tell the criteria that the comma should represent the OR function. I am new to Access and trying to learn, but I am not even sure what to search to find my answer - I have been searching for over an hour and nothing seems to be the solution to my problem. I understand if I use the following text in the criteria field I can return the information for one order:

```
[Forms]![Supplies Needed for Order]![Order ID]
```

How do I allow for multiple OrderID search in one form field?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - I flagged the question to see if moderators can move it.

Comment: One approach is to use InStr() function. However, relying on user to input string consistently is guaranteed to fail at some point. Another approach is to use multi-select listbox and VBA builds filter criteria using IN() to apply to form or report.